# JBPM 6 Runtime Manager Initialization Exception with releaseId configurations

Tags: jpa, drools, jbpm, kie, kie-workbench

I have created a spring mvc project for JBPM6.1 . I am geting the following exception whenever I am creating an environment with releaseId passed in DEFAULTBUILDER method.

*

> No active JTA transaction on joinTransaction call

*

I am creating RuntimeManager with environment referring to ReleaseId. The kJar properly gets downloaded but gives the below error.  It works fine when I pick the asset from classpath. Process instance also runs and works fine.

```
Design and Deploy Part
      I have created one BPMN2 workflow in Kie-Workbench 6.1.0 Final. I deployed the KJar to nexus repository. KJar also contains the attached kmodule.xml.

Application-JBPM integration

RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder builder = RuntimeEnvironmentBuilder.Factory.get()
.newDefaultBuilder("com.emi","tools.itsr","1.0.2", "kbase", "ksessionbpmn")
.entityManagerFactory(jbpmEMF);


builder.userGroupCallback(new UserGroupCallBackImpl());


runtimeMgr = RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get()
.newSingletonRuntimeManager(builder.get(), "org.jbpm:Evaluation:1.0");


runtimeEngine = runtimeMgr.getRuntimeEngine(null);
ksessionBpm = runtimeEngine.getKieSession();
bpmTaskService = runtimeEngine.getTaskService()
```

;

But getting following exception on

```
RuntimeManagerFactory.Factory.get().newSingletonRuntimeManager(builder.get(), "org.jbpm:Evaluation:1.0");
```

Exception

> 14:57:34,976WARN[org.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService](http-> > /127.0.0.1:8080-1)Couldnotcommitsession:javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:NoactiveJTAtransactiononjoinTransactioncall
>   atorg.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1233)[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1183)[hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)[spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:317)[spring-orm-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.joinTransaction(UnknownSource)
>   atorg.drools.persistence.jpa.JpaPersistenceContext.joinTransaction(JpaPersistenceContext.java:66)[drools-persistence-jpa-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.(SingleSessionCommandService.java:102)[drools-persistence-jpa-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atsun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeMethod)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atsun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atsun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atjava.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:150)[drools-persistence-jpa-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:70)[drools-persistence-jpa-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)[drools-persistence-jpa-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.kie.internal.persistence.jpa.JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(JPAKnowledgeService.java:121)[kie-internal-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.JPASessionFactory.newKieSession(JPASessionFactory.java:42)[jbpm-runtime-manager-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SingletonRuntimeManager.init(SingletonRuntimeManager.java:95)[jbpm-runtime-manager-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atorg.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:71)[jbpm-runtime-manager-6.1.0.Final.jar:6.1.0.Final]
>   atcom.emirates.workflow.service.impl.ProcessServiceImpl.createRuntimeManager(ProcessServiceImpl.java:76)[classes:]
>   atcom.emirates.workflow.service.impl.ProcessServiceImpl.startProcess(ProcessServiceImpl.java:51)[classes:]
>   atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atorg.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)[spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)[spring-aop-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.startProcess(UnknownSource)
>   atcom.emirates.workflow.service.impl.WorkflowServiceImpl.startProcess(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:25)[classes:]
>   atcom.emirates.workflow.controller.JbpmController.fetchProcessTaskDetails(JbpmController.java:46)[classes:]
>   atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
>   atorg.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)[spring-web-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)[jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)[spring-webmvc-4.0.1.RELEASE.jar:4.0.1.RELEASE]
>   atjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)[jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)[jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>   atorg.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)[jboss-as-jpa-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>   atorg.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)[jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atorg.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)[jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
>   atjava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)[rt.jar:1.7.0_72]

14:57:35,033ERRORstderrjava.lang.IllegalStateException:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
14:57:35,035ERRORstderratorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:164)
14:57:35,035ERRORstderratorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:70)
14:57:35,035ERRORstderratorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.newKieSession(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:39)
14:57:35,035ERRORstderratorg.kie.internal.persistence.jpa.JPAKnowledgeService.newStatefulKnowledgeSession(JPAKnowledgeService.java:121)
14:57:35,036ERRORstderratorg.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.JPASessionFactory.newKieSession(JPASessionFactory.java:42)
14:57:35,036ERRORstderratorg.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.SingletonRuntimeManager.init(SingletonRuntimeManager.java:95)
14:57:35,036ERRORstderratorg.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newSingletonRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:71)
14:57:35,036ERRORstderratcom.emirates.workflow.service.impl.ProcessServiceImpl.createRuntimeManager(ProcessServiceImpl.java:76)
14:57:35,037ERRORstderratcom.emirates.workflow.service.impl.ProcessServiceImpl.startProcess(ProcessServiceImpl.java:51)
14:57:35,037ERRORstderratsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)
14:57:35,037ERRORstderratsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:57:35,038ERRORstderratsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:57:35,038ERRORstderratjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:57:35,038ERRORstderratorg.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
14:57:35,038ERRORstderratorg.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:201)
14:57:35,039ERRORstderratcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy76.startProcess(UnknownSource)
14:57:35,039ERRORstderratcom.emirates.workflow.service.impl.WorkflowServiceImpl.startProcess(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:25)
14:57:35,039ERRORstderratcom.emirates.workflow.controller.JbpmController.fetchProcessTaskDetails(JbpmController.java:46)
14:57:35,039ERRORstderratsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(NativeMethod)
14:57:35,039ERRORstderratsun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:57:35,040ERRORstderratsun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
14:57:35,040ERRORstderratjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
14:57:35,040ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:214)
14:57:35,040ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:132)
14:57:35,041ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:104)
14:57:35,041ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandleMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:749)
14:57:35,041ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:690)
14:57:35,042ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:83)
14:57:35,042ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)
14:57:35,042ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)
14:57:35,042ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
14:57:35,043ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
14:57:35,043ERRORstderratjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:754)
14:57:35,043ERRORstderratorg.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
14:57:35,044ERRORstderratjavax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847)
14:57:35,044ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295)
14:57:35,044ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
14:57:35,044ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230)
14:57:35,044ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149)
14:57:35,045ERRORstderratorg.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
14:57:35,045ERRORstderratorg.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50)
14:57:35,045ERRORstderratorg.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169)
14:57:35,045ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145)
14:57:35,046ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97)
14:57:35,046ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102)
14:57:35,046ERRORstderratorg.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336)
14:57:35,046ERRORstderratorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856)
14:57:35,047ERRORstderratorg.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653)
14:57:35,047ERRORstderratorg.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920)
14:57:35,047ERRORstderratjava.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
14:57:35,048ERRORstderrCausedby:java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
14:57:35,048ERRORstderratsun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(NativeMethod)
14:57:35,048ERRORstderratsun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
14:57:35,048ERRORstderratsun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
14:57:35,048ERRORstderratjava.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
14:57:35,049ERRORstderratorg.drools.persistence.jpa.KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.buildCommandService(KnowledgeStoreServiceImpl.java:150)
14:57:35,049ERRORstderr...49more
14:57:35,049ERRORstderrCausedby:javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException:NoactiveJTAtransactiononjoinTransactioncall
14:57:35,049ERRORstderratorg.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1233)
14:57:35,050ERRORstderratorg.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.joinTransaction(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1183)
14:57:35,050ERRORstderratorg.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.doJoinTransaction(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:350)
14:57:35,053ERRORstderratorg.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:317)
14:57:35,053ERRORstderratcom.sun.proxy.$Proxy90.joinTransaction(UnknownSource)
14:57:35,053ERRORstderratorg.drools.persistence.jpa.JpaPersistenceContext.joinTransaction(JpaPersistenceContext.java:66)
14:57:35,054ERRORstderratorg.drools.persistence.SingleSessionCommandService.(SingleSessionCommandService.java:102)
14:57:35,054ERRORstderr...54more

Comment: Hello, @learner, could you show your entity manager's config? Also I was facing a similar issue with jbpm6.2.0 and eclipselink and the reason was about problems with named queries provided by jbpm jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea. I got it fixed. One reason was that Task audit. XML was missing and the second reason was that I was injecting the task service along with runtime manager.